# How do I properly escape tweets to send as JSON to socket.io?

Tags: java, regex, twitter, socket.io

I am using the [socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) to send a JSON object of tweets that I am listening for to my node.js server. After some time, the socket disconnects and I receive this error:

```
io.socket.SocketIOException: 1+0
at io.socket.IOConnection.transportMessage(IOConnection.java:725)
at io.socket.WebsocketTransport.onMessage(WebsocketTransport.java:117)
at de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketReceiver.run(WebSocketReceiver.java:57)
Aug 9, 2012 10:05:45 AM io.socket.IOConnection cleanup
INFO: Cleanup
```

The issue seems to be caused by certain tweets with problematic characters. JSON my program attempted to send:

```
Aug 9, 2012 10:05:43 AM io.socket.IOConnection sendPlain
INFO: > 5:::{"args":[{"message":"#TBT #WatchTheThrone #Yeezy #JayZ #LA One of the most epic concerts of my life. ? http://t.co/6WVaZgIM","user":"ElleBxo"}],"name":"p5tweet"}
Aug 9, 2012 10:05:45 AM io.socket.IOConnection sendPlain
```

vs. the actual tweet on twitter: "#TBT #WatchTheThrone #Yeezy #JayZ #LA One of the most epic concerts of my life.  http://instagr.am/p/OHXPQxxUe7/ " https://twitter.com/ElleBxo/status/233610010066821121

There seems to be a weird discrepancy where my JSON sees " ? " in front of the instagram link where on twitter it's simply "   ". Below is my problematic code. I tried doing a replaceAll() on the string, but it does not guarantee the error from throwing and disconnecting my socket. I have also seen other characters cause this error, so I am not sure what they all are.

```
Map<String,String> mp=new HashMap<String, String>();
Status tweet = (Status)queue.get(0);
String safeTweet = tweet.text().replaceAll(" ? ", " ");
mp.put("user",tweet.user().screenName());
mp.put("message",safeTweet);
JSONObject tweetJSON = new JSONObject(mp);
socket.emit("p5tweet", tweetJSON);
```

How can I properly escape the tweet string to prevent this from happening? Thanks!! :)

EDIT: another tweet that breaks the connection. It seems like links are causing it in general:

```
 {"args":[{"message":"RT @Olympics: Congrats to the first woman ever to win an Olympic #Boxing gold medal - Nicola Adams of Team GBR #olympics http://t.co/Jab ...","user":"GlockQueen31"}],"name":"p5tweet"}
```

on twitter:
"Congrats to the first woman ever to win an Olympic #Boxing gold medal - Nicola Adams of Team GBR #olympics pic.twitter.com/JabAjIrl"

Comment: The character isn't blank, or `?`, it's a gem stone: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f48e/index.htm

Comment: I strongly suspect you have called `new String(byte[])` somewhere. What is `Status`? Is it your own object?

Comment: `Status` is not my own object so it is possible, but I do not see `new String(byte[])` while looking through the [library's source](https://github.com/mccv/processing-tweet-stream). I am using the Processing library [Tweet Stream](http://mccv.github.com/processing-tweet-stream/reference/index.html) for receiving tweets. My program is actually written in [Processing](http://processing.org/), but I have been including more Java libraries as the program has gotten more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Tweet Stream. Line 242 of

https://github.com/mccv/processing-tweet-stream/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/twitter/processing/TweetStream.scala

`reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))`

This doesn't take encoding into account, and uses the platform default. If the HTTP response's encoding matches your platform, it will be OK, otherwise it will mangle non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Oh I see! I am not familiar with scala, unfortunately. How can I add encoding to this line to get it to match the encoding that my Java program needs to send to my node server?

Comment: Once you have a `String`, you don't need to worry about matching encoding. It's creating the `String` that's the problem. That line ought to be reading the charset from the HTTP Content-Encoding header and using it in the `InputStreamReader` constructor. It's rather complicated to get all the edge cases right though - you might be better off using something like HTTP Components http://hc.apache.org/