# Socket io errors during receiving

Tags: android, json, socket.io

I am making android application using socket io by using library Gottox/socket.io-java-client i sent the data successfully to the server but i have problems in receiving responses from the server i got these errors

```
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at a.a.a.SocketsActivity$1.onClick(SocketsActivity.java:121)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-14 01:31:43.441: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 01:31:48.433: I/global(585): Default buffer size used in BufferedOutputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
09-14 01:31:49.481: I/io.socket(585): > 3:::{"Action":  "AuthenticateUser","Parameters":[{"UserName": "a","Password": "a"}]}
09-14 01:31:49.481: I/io.socket(585): < 1::
09-14 01:31:50.681: I/io.socket(585): < 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"Action":"AuthenticateUser","RequestStatus":"100","RequestStatusMessage":"Invalid UserName/password"}]}
09-14 01:31:50.681: W/System.err(585): a.a.a.SocketIOException: Exception was thrown in on(String, JSONObject[]).
09-14 01:31:50.681: W/System.err(585): Message was: 5:::{"name":"message","args":[{"Action":"AuthenticateUser","RequestStatus":"100","RequestStatusMessage":"Invalid UserName/password"}]}
09-14 01:31:50.691: W/System.err(585):  at a.a.a.IOConnection.transportMessage(IOConnection.java:684)
09-14 01:31:50.691: W/System.err(585):  at a.a.a.WebsocketTransport.onMessage(WebsocketTransport.java:99)
09-14 01:31:50.691: W/System.err(585):  at de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketReceiver.run(WebSocketReceiver.java:57)
09-14 01:31:50.691: W/System.err(585): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: a.a.a.IOConnection
09-14 01:31:50.691: W/System.err(585):  at a.a.a.IOConnection.findCallback(IOConnection.java:487)
09-14 01:31:50.701: W/System.err(585):  at a.a.a.IOConnection.transportMessage(IOConnection.java:679)
09-14 01:31:50.701: W/System.err(585):  ... 2 more
```

here it is my code

```
private void SendDataToServer(String username,String password)
    {
          SocketIO socket=new SocketIO();
        try {
            socket = new SocketIO("http://41.69.103.53:1333/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
          socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
              public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                  try {


                      System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
             //         x=json.toString(2);
              //        z=json.toString();

                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();

                  }
              }

              public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                //tv.setText(data);
                  //System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
                //  x=data;
              }

              public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                //tv.setText(socketIOException.toString());
                //System.out.println("an Error occured");
                  request=0;
                  socketIOException.printStackTrace();
              }

              public void onDisconnect() {
              //    tv.setText("Connection terminated.");
                  //System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
                  request=0;
              }

              public void onConnect() {
              //    tv.setText("Connection terminated.");
                //  System.out.println("Connection established");
              }

              public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                //tv.setText("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
                 // System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
                  x=event;
              }
          });

          // This line is cached until the connection is establisched.
          String request="{\"Action\":  \"AuthenticateUser\""+","+
                  "\"Parameters\":";
          String request_2="[{"+"\"UserName\": "+"\""+username_string+"\""+","+
           "\"Password\""+": "+"\""+password_string+"\""+"}]}";
          String FinalRequest_login=request+request_2;
          socket.send(FinalRequest_login);



    }
```

i found the line that causes the exception

```
public void transportMessage(String text) {
        logger.info("< " + text);
        IOMessage message;
        try {
            message = new IOMessage(text);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error(new SocketIOException("Garbage from server: " + text, e));
            return;
        }
        resetTimeout();
switch (message.getType()) {
        case IOMessage.TYPE_DISCONNECT:
            try {
                findCallback(message).onDisconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error(new SocketIOException(
                        "Exception was thrown in onDisconnect()", e));
            }
            break;
case IOMessage.TYPE_EVENT:
            try {
                JSONObject event = new JSONObject(message.getData());
                Object[] argsArray;
                if (event.has("args")) {
                    JSONArray args = event.getJSONArray("args");
                    argsArray = new Object[args.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++) {
                        if (args.isNull(i) == false)
                            argsArray[i] = args.get(i);
                    }
                } else
                    argsArray = new Object[0];
                String eventName = event.getString("name");
                try {
                    findCallback(message).on(eventName,
                            remoteAcknowledge(message), argsArray);
                } **catch (Exception e) {
                    error(new SocketIOException(
                            "Exception was thrown in on(String, JSONObject[]).\n"
                                    + "Message was: " + message.toString(), e));**
                }
```

this is the Exception 
**catch (Exception e) {
                    error(new SocketIOException(
                            "Exception was thrown in on(String, JSONObject[]).\n"
                                    + "Message was: " + message.toString(), e));**

because of this function

```
public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
    for (SocketIO socket : sockets.values())
            socket.getCallback().on(event, ack, args);
    }
```

can anyone fix it to me or help me why do i get this exception??thanks in advance

Comment: I see this in the stack trace, is that expected? [{"Action":"AuthenticateUser","RequestStatus":"100","RequestStatusMessage":"Invalid UserName/password"}]

Comment: yes this is the message that i supposed to receive it

Comment: @RobertPeters  I supposed to receive a JSONObject but i don't know why all these errors appeared

Comment: Sorry can't be much help remotely. Did you see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888955/how-do-i-properly-escape-tweets-to-send-as-json-to-socket-io Maybe, you are getting the json, but there is a parsing issue.

Answer (score 0):

then try this at on method :

```
@Override
        public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
            Object[] a = args;

            Log.d("app", a[0].toString());
}           
    });
```

i parsed args object into object array first, then i call the value at 0 index

but it depends on server response, you can see the log for detailed server response